# JAXB un-marshaling return null

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class with the following structure

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({
Child.class
})
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable{}
```

And

```
public class Child extends Parent implements Serializable{


  private String attribute;

  private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>() ;
}
```

So while marshaling a child object it is saved successfully at the database as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Child >
    <attribute>age</attribute>
    <values>1</values>
    <values>2</values>
</Child >
```

The problem is while un-marshaling that object , The unmarshal function return null.

```
JAXB.unmarshal(reader, Parent.class)
```

Could you please advise what is the problem , and how to solve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which function returns null,Please elaborate

Comment: The unmarshal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unmarshalling, you must:

- Provide as root of your XML an element marked with @XMLRootElement.
- Define your classes as fully compliant Java Beans (get/set methods over attributes).

Here is the code that worked for me:
**Parent.java**

```
package dummy;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({
Child.class
})
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable{}
```

**Child (with a small main method marshalling and unmarshalling the same payload)**

```
package dummy;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Child extends Parent implements Serializable
{

private String attribute;

private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * @return the attribute
 */
public String getAttribute()
{
    return attribute;
}

/**
 * @param attribute
 *            the attribute to set
 */
public void setAttribute(String attribute)
{
    this.attribute = attribute;
}

/**
 * @return the values
 */
public List<String> getValues()
{
    return values;
}

/**
 * @param values
 *            the values to set
 */
public void setValues(List<String> values)
{
    this.values = values;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
{
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);

    Child child = new Child();
    child.setAttribute("dummy");
    child.setValues(Arrays.asList("value1", "value2"));

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    context.createMarshaller().marshal(child, writer);

    System.out.println(writer.getBuffer().toString());

    Child unmarshalledChild = (Child) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new    ByteArrayInputStream(writer.getBuffer().toString().getBytes()));
    System.out.println("attribute: " + unmarshalledChild.attribute);
    System.out.println("values: " + unmarshalledChild.values);

}
```

}

**And the successful output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><child>   <attribute>dummy</attribute><values>value1</values><values>value2</values></child>
attribute: dummy
values: [value1, value2]
```

Comment: Thanks Victor for you reply and your effort :) you guide me to the problem which is that while unmarshalling am using the Parent.class not child.class as it will be another children so i want to unmarshal to the parent , so the unmarshell retusn with null value , so do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: Hi, I think that unmarshalling to Parent will be hard as it is an abstract class. However you can always cast to Parent (as Child extends Parent). However, if you want to define Parent/Children relatioship perhaps you should try composition over inheritance (that is, that every element has a list of children as attribute)